# Chromatic index

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that if $G$ is a graph with $m$ edges and $m> {a}'(G)*\Delta(G)
> $, then $\chi {}'(G)=\Delta (G)+1$, where $\chi {}'(G)$ is chromatic index of graph $G$, ${a}'(G)$ is matching number of graph $G$ and $\Delta(G)$ is maximum degree of graph $G$.

I know that every color class in edge coloring forms independent edge set. But how it helps with proving the statement?

Comment: What are $a'(G)$ and $\Delta(G)$ and $\chi'(G)$?

Comment: @Arthur I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Vizing's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem), we have that $\Delta(G) \le \chi'(G) \le \Delta(G)+1$. So, it is sufficient to prove that having only $\Delta(G)$ colours won't lead us to any proper edge colouring of $G$. Suppose that the contrary happens, i.e. there exists a proper edge colouring with $\Delta(G)$ colours. The size of each colour class is at most $a'(G)$, since the any colour class consists of independent edges. As we have $\Delta(G)$ classes and the colour classes define a partition for the vertex set, it follows that the sum of the size of all colour classes, that is $m$, must be at most $a'(G)\Delta(G)$, which contradicts the assumption.

Comment: Thank you so much